# Массив указателей типа void (функция удаления, расширения)

Tags: c++

Вот есть задание создать такую структуру данных как изображена на изображении

[image: img]

Вот не как не могу нормально написать функцию удаление элемента и расширения , ну и соответственно удаление всего списка.
Постоянно выскакивает сообщение типа "`SIGABRT`" . 
Немного о структуре. Массив из указателей типа `void*`, каждый из указателей в массиве указывает на структуру, за исключением 2 первых элементов, они берутся как служебные `.size` – размер массива (количество элементов, на которое рассчитан массив), `count` – реальное количество элементов в списке.
 Затем указатель на начало массива передвигается на 2 элемента вперед , соответственно нулевой элемент будет 3 на самом деле.

Подскажите пожалуйста где накосячил . 
Вот код. 
pointerarray.cpp

```
#include "pointerarray.h"
pointerArray::pointerArray(int initialSize)
{
     this->start = new void* [initialSize+2];/* запрашиваем память для  нового массива*/
    this->initArr(initialSize);

}

pointerArray::pointerArray()
{
     this->start = new void* [DEF_SIZE+2]; /* запрашиваем память для  нового массива*/
    this->initArr(DEF_SIZE);

}

void pointerArray::initArr(int initSize) {
    this->start+=2;  /*опускаем указатель вниз на два элемента чтобы он указывал на первый указатель а не на служебный элемент*/


    ((int*)this->start)[POS_CNT]  = 0; /*Заполняем служебный элемент массива – количество элементов списка*/

    ((int*)this->start)[POS_SZ]  =  initSize; /*Заполняем служебыій элемент массива – размер массива */
}

void pointerArray::ExpendArrPtr (){
    expandDef(((int*)this->start)[POS_SZ],DELTA);
}

void** pointerArray::getStart() {
    return this->start;
}

void pointerArray::ExpendArrPtr (int incSize)
{
  expandDef(((int*)this->start)[POS_SZ],incSize);
}
void pointerArray::expandDef (int sizeOld,int incSize) {

    int  sizeNew = sizeOld + incSize;
  void**   arOld = this->start; /*вспомогательный бестиповый указатель на начало массива указателей*/
  this->start = new void* [sizeNew+2]; /*выделение места для нового массива*/


  for (int i = sizeOld; i>= 0; i--)
  {
      this->start[i]=arOld[i];
  }

   arOld-=2;
   ((int*)this->start)[POS_CNT]  = ((int*)arOld)[POS_CNT];
   ((int*)this->start)[POS_SZ]  = sizeNew;

  delete []arOld; //освобождаем память
    this->start+=2; /* ставим указатель массива на первый указатель в новом массиве */
}

void pointerArray::showList() {
    int cnt=((int*)this->start)[POS_CNT];
    for (int k = 0; k <cnt; k++)
        {
          cout<<((TStruct*)this->start[k])->name<<"\n";
          cout<<((TStruct*)this->start[k])->age<<"\n";
        }
 }
int pointerArray::findElList(string key){
    /* start – указатель на список
      key – ключ поиска
      posFndEl – индекс найденного элемента
      findOk – результат поиска (true – если найден элемент,
               false – если не найден элемент с таким ключом)
   */
 int posFndEl;
 int    middl; /*middl выступает как индекс среднего элемента
              массива*/
 int     hi, low;   /*текущие границы - верхняя, нижняя*/    /*элемент не найден*/

      /*берем из мссива значение служебного элемента cunt
        И проверяем пуст ли список*/

 if (((int*)this->start)[POS_CNT] == 0)
 {
    posFndEl = 0;
    return -1;
 }
      /*Устанавливаем границы поиска на границы массива*/
 low = 0;
 hi = ((int*)this->start)[POS_CNT] - 1;

 do
 {
    middl = (hi + low) / 2 ; /*индекс среднего элемента*/

     if (key==((TStruct*)(this->start[middl]))->name)
        { posFndEl = middl;      /*элемент найден*/
        return posFndEl;
        }
     if (key<((TStruct*)(this->start[middl]))->name)
        {
          hi = middl - 1;
       }
     else
        {
         low = middl + 1;
       }

 } while  (low <= hi);
 posFndEl= -1;
 return posFndEl;/*Перебран весь массив. Искомый элемент не найден. Определена позиция возможной вставки нового элемента*/
}
void pointerArray::replaceEl(void* newEl,int place){
    if (place<0) {
        return;
    }
     delete ((TStruct*)(this->start[place]));
     this->start[place] = newEl;
}
void pointerArray::replaceEl(int age ,string name,int place){
    if (place<0) {
        return;
    }
    ((TStruct*)(this->start[place]))->age = age;
    ((TStruct*)(this->start[place]))->name = name;

}

void pointerArray::delFromList(int posDel){
int cnt=((int*)this->start)[POS_CNT];
if (posDel<0){
    return;
}
      cout<<(TStruct*)this->start[posDel];
         for (int k = posDel; k<cnt-1; k++)
              {
             this->start[k] = this->start[k+1];
         }
cnt--;
       ((int*)this->start)[POS_CNT]=cnt;

}
void pointerArray::addToSort(void* pnew, int posAdd)
{
    /*
         start – указатель на список
         pnew – указатель на новый элемент списка, который размещен
                     в памяти  и поля его заполнены
         posAdd – индекс элемента в массиве, в который необходимо вставить
                         указатель на новый элемент
    */

int cnt=((int*)this->start)[POS_CNT];
int sz= ((int*)this->start)[POS_SZ];

  //если массив переполнен, то вызываем расширение массива
if (cnt == sz)
        {
       this->ExpendArrPtr();
        }


 if (posAdd == cnt) //добавляемый элемент располагается в конце списка
        {
        this->start[posAdd] = pnew;
        }
  else
        {     // сдвиг элементов в массиве указателей на 1 вправо
         for (int k = cnt-1; k >= posAdd; k--)
              {
                  this->start[k+1] = this->start[k];}
                  this->start[posAdd] = pnew;
               }
 cnt++;

 ((int*)this->start)[POS_CNT]=cnt;
} //addToSort
void pointerArray::showInfo() {
    cout<<((int*)this->start)[POS_CNT]<<"\n";
     cout<<((int*)this->start)[POS_SZ];
}
```

Pointerarray.h

```
#ifndef POINTERARRAY_H
#define POINTERARRAY_H

#define POS_SZ 2
#define POS_CNT -1
#define DEF_SIZE 10
#define DELTA 4

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef struct {
         int age;
         string name;
   } TStruct;


class pointerArray {
public:
    pointerArray(int initialSize);
    pointerArray();
    void showList ();
    void delFromList(int posDel);
    void ExpendArrPtr ();
    void ExpendArrPtr (int incSize);
    int findElList(string key);
    void showInfo();
    void addToSort(void* pnew, int posAdd);
    void** getStart();
    void replaceEl(void* newEl,int place);
    void replaceEl(int age ,string name,int place);
    void delFromList();
     ~pointerArray() {
};
private:
     void** start;
     void initArr(int initSize);
     void expandDef (int sizeOld,int incSize);
};

#endif // POINTERARRAY_H
```

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    pointerArray arr(3);
    void* el = new TStruct;
    ((TStruct*)el)->age =35;
    ((TStruct*)el)->name = "One";
    void* el1 = new TStruct;
    ((TStruct*)el1)->age =2;
    ((TStruct*)el1)->name = "Two";
    void* el2 = new TStruct;
    ((TStruct*)el2)->age =3;
    ((TStruct*)el2)->name = "three";
     void* el3 = new TStruct;
    ((TStruct*)el3)->age =6;
    ((TStruct*)el3)->name = "four";

    arr.addToSort(el,0);
    arr.addToSort(el1,1);
    arr.addToSort(el2,2);
    arr.addToSort(el3,3);
   arr.delFromList(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Спасибо заранее

Comment: @Alexandr Crospov, я бы посоветовал Вам использовать для выделения памяти *`realloc()`*, вместо `new` и `delete`.

Посмотрите `man 3 realloc`.

Comment: @avp: тогда уж и `malloc`/`free` вместо `new`/`delete`, `realloc` не должен хорошо сочетаться с `new`.

Comment: @VladD, так я же и написал, вмест**о**. 

При желании можно использовать один лишь `realloc`. Хотя наличие `malloc` и `free`, конечно, делают код более понятным.

Comment: @avp: не знал, что `realloc` справляется с `NULL` в качестве аргумента.

Comment: realloc может ещё и память освобождать, если передать нулевой размер:)

Answer (score 2):

О боже! кто до этого додумался? я думаю что или составитель задания или вы что то намудрили...

судя по всему вам нужно реализовать структуру данных  vector(динамический массив) или array(статический массив).

не надо хранить размер и ёмкость массива в самом массиве!

1. глупо
2. геморрой со сдвигами вперёд назад от
       нулевого элемента
3. переполнение

не надо использовать void указатели! из за них получите геморрой с проверкой типов, лучше воспользуйтесь шаблонами! (они как раз для этого и созданы)

**update**

сделайте шаблонный класс внутри которого храните 3 переменные (приватные)

1. capacity (ёмкость)
2. size (текущий размер)
3. шаблонный указатель на начало массива

и перегрузите оператор `operator[]()` чтобы можно было работать как с обычным массивом, ну и про доп. функции не забудьте ...

p.s. и vector и array есть и в  stl и boost и в инете, я даже как то на т.ру нашел видеоуроки :)

p.s.s. вам будет полезно посмотреть [vector из STL](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/),  [array из STL](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/)

Comment: Нужно именно по такой схеме как я описал , так поставлено задание

Comment: то есть чёрным по белому написано: "приказываю хранить capacity and size в первых двух ячейках памяти массива. `число____ подпись____`" ? 

а где дают такие задания?

Comment: к сожалению так и есть . Дают еще такие задания

Comment: ого! не завидую вам с такими заданиями...

а можно фото или скрин этого задания? (уж очень хочется показать сие чудо знакомым)

ну или хотябы скажите где такое задают?(хотябы город) буду знать заведения от которых надо держаться подальше


кстати если это переделать и сделать нормально, то в памяти это будет расположено так же как на [картинке][1] тогда можно сослаться мол "я сделал как на картинке, в памяти ПК так и будет расположено!"


  [1]: http://s12.postimg.org/mqd3wuxf1/image.png

Answer (score 2):

IMHO вот тут нестыковочка

```
#define POS_SZ 2
#define POS_CNT -1

....

void pointerArray::initArr(int initSize) {
    this->start+=2;  /*опускаем указатель вниз на два элемента чтобы он указывал на  первый указатель а не на служебный элемент*/

    ((int*)this->start)[POS_CNT]  = 0; /*Заполняем служебный элемент массива – количество элементов списка*/

    ((int*)this->start)[POS_SZ]  =  initSize; /*Заполняем служебыій элемент массива – размер массива */
}
```

нужно

```
#define POS_SZ (-2)
```

Вообще, возьмите за правило заключать выражения в define в скобки.

Кстати, недавно тут где-то была ссылочка на то, как Шилдта (если не ошибаюсь) за такое лицом по лавке возили.

Answer (score 1):

Мы писали в институте задания с самописными структурами данных. Но

1. Почему count и size хранятся в массиве? Это так делали ещё на доОППшном ассемблере...
2. Почему вам надо хранить это обязательно в массиве??? А потом при расширении придётся ВСЕ данные копировать в новый массив... да и память придётся выделять-убивать.

Вы изучали принципы построения стеков там, списков, аррейЛистов? ProkletyiPirat правильно вам говорит что по-хорошему надо пользоваться шаблонами, это не потребует от вас написания собственноручно структур данных, но если вам их написание нужно в учебных планах то во-первых определитесь как он будет использоваться - добавлять элементы можно лишь в одну сторону или в обоих, можно ли удалять, удалять лишь с последний элемент или можно удалять элементы из середины? Потому что если удаление точно может быть только с конца(ов) или вообще его нет - то вам лучше клепать список массивов (в т.ч. можно расширять в оба направления), удалять с конца - будете хранить индекс последнего элемента и просто его удалите и декриментите индекс. А вот если надо удалять не только с конца(ов) - то вам придётся делать список где элементом списка будет единичный "указатель на элемент". Но это сделает навигацию по индексу очень долгой, пропорционально зависящей можно сказать от числа элементов, потому что чтобы перейти на следующий элемент вам надо знать ссылку на него в предыдущем. Вернее тут как в базах данных - если обращение осуществляется часто а удаление - редко то лучше держать в массиве или списке массивов и при каждом удалении физически передвигать всю информацию, если обращение - редко, а удаление - часто то лучше держать в списке (в базах её при редком удалении и частом обращении после внесения изменений как-то там сортируют, индексируют). Или же если уж хотите сделать всё вообще очень круто - то можно пойти на изощрения и продумать там массивы указателей для более быстрого навигирования по ним или всякие другие всячины. ....

Да извините разговорился приятно ощутить что хоть кому-то потребовалась реальная помощь от тех наработок. Можете скачать книгу Павловская Т.А. "Программирование на языке высокого уровня". (по C++ а не C#) там прямо примеры коды с созданием списков и т.д. Вот кстати ссыль http://vk.com/doc81521652_220095882 Ещё можете посмотреть нашу методичку с первого курса http://vk.com/doc81521652_49455579